# DateTime: how to display as DD.MM.YYYY?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got DateTime variable and i want to convert it to string "DD.MM.YYYY"
Please note, the values must be separated by "dot" sign.

Of course I can do manual string composition. But I wonder if I can use `DateTime.ToString()`
to do required conversion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
string formatted = dt.ToString("dd'.'MM'.'yyyy");
```

Now in this case the quotes aren't actually required, as [custom date/time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) don't interpret dot in any special way. However, I like to make it explicit - if change '.' for ':' for example, then while it's quoted it will stay with the explicit character, but unquoted it would be "the culture-specific time separator". It wasn't entirely obvious to me whether "." would be interpreted as "the culture-specific decimal separator" or not, hence the quoting. You may feel that's over the top, of course - it's entirely your decision.

You *may* also want to specify the invariant culture, just to remove any other traces of doubt:

```
string formatted = dt.ToString("dd'.'MM'.'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(At that point the quotes around the dot become less relevant, as "." is the decimal separator in the invariant culture anyway.)

Comment: +1: Thanks for the detailed information regarding the quotes any their meaning in this case.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use DateTime.ToString like this:

```
myDateVariable.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Note that you have to use capital MM here, since mm evaluates to minutes instead of months.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative for you:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

German's use `.` as the date separator.

Comment: Do you really want everyone reading the code to have to know that though? Isn't it simpler to spell it out?

Comment: Also, I believe it's possible to override any culture with your own settings, so that's not guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: note the word **alternative**, thanks for the heads up anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can format the date like this:

```
date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

When formatting numbers the period `.` will change depending on the `CultureInfo` used, but not when formatting dates.

If you are verifying your code against the code analysis rule [CA1304: Specify CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182189.aspx) you will have to use the invariant culture even though it doesn't matter for this particular format:

```
date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```